# How to validate the DropDownList and Update Database on a single click inside a GridView Control in ASP .NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have one `GridView` inside an update panel. Last column of the `GridView` has a `LinkButton` (`ID="lnkUpdate"`). This `LinkButton` is used to Validate a few `DropDowns` in other Columns of `GridView` using JavaScript function (Validate(lnkUpdate)).

I want to update the Data in a DataBase using this `LinkButton`. I can successfully update the data in the database if I use `OnClick="btnSave_Data_Click"` however, I have to remove `OnClientClick="return Validate(this)"`.

Can the experts in the forum help me find a way to keep both of these events. I mean I want to be able to Update the Database as well as Validate the `DropDownList`.

What I have tried:

The code for Validate(lnkUpdate) is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate(lnkUpdate) {
        var txtIncident, ddlStatus, ddlReason;
        var row = lnkUpdate.parentNode.parentNode;
        var controls = row.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
            if (controls[i].id.indexOf("txtIncident") != -1) {
                txtIncident = controls[i];
            }
            if (controls[i].id.indexOf("ddlStatus") != -1) {
                ddlStatus = controls[i];
            }
            if (controls[i].id.indexOf("ddlReason") != -1) {
                ddlReason = controls[i];
            }

        }
        var message = "";
        if (ddlStatus.value == "") {
            message += "Please select Status";
        } else if ((ddlStatus.value == "Make") && (ddlReason.value == "")) {
            message += "Please select Reason";
        } else if ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "")) {
            message += "Please select Reason";
        } else if (
            ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Data Availablility: Customer") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Data Availablility: Dell Other") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Data Availablility: Dell Reporting Team") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Data Availablility: Vendor") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Data Integrity: Customer") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Data Integrity: Dell Other") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Data Integrity: Dell Reporting Team") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Data Integrity: Vendor") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Duplicate Instance") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "External Factors") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            || ((ddlStatus.value == "Miss") && (ddlReason.value == "Report Modifications: Customer") && (txtIncident.value == ""))
            ) {
            message += "Please enter Incident#";
        } else {


        }
        //Display error message.
        if (message != "") {
            alert(message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

and the code for btnSave_Data_Click is:

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Data_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave_Data.Click
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "sp_Insrt_Updt_Rcrd"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Report_Date", Today())
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Report_Time", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Effort", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Method", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Format", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Incident", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Support_Region", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Badge", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime_IST_India", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime_CST_Round_Rock", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime_MST_Cyberjaya", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime_GMT_Casablanca", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Week_Working_Day_Number", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month_Working_Day_Number", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NT_Login", "")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Report_UID", Today() & "Finally_03")

Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
cmd.Connection = con
con.Open()
sda.SelectCommand = cmd
sda.Fill(dt)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can call javascript from server side button click using,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);
```

Comment: "lnkUpdate" is inside the gridview in a templatedfield, it is not an independent server control.

Comment: private void btnSave_Data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Your code to update data 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","Validate()",true);
}

Comment: I have tried this and it's not working can you correct my code? Protected Sub btnSave_Data_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave_Data.Click Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "Validate", "Validate(lnkUpdate)", True) ... End Sub

Comment: even the simple code like:
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "<script type=text/javascript>alert('hi')</script>", True)
is not working

Comment: Please check I have added the two blocks of code which work independently. I want to combine these two.